# Work done in unwinding of a chord, wound around a disc

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

As I understand the work done in case of circular motion is the product of torque and displacement.

Let's say the amount of chord that is unwound is x and torque be t, in my textbook I'm given the work done to be x*t, but x is only the measurement of the arc that is unwound and not the displacement that takes place from a point anywhere on the disk. So wouldn't the work done be the displacement*torque.

Comment: It's wrong. The dimensions of τ.r is [M][L]^3[T]^-2.

Answer (score 0):

You can change from linear equations to rotational quantities like this:

$Work = Force \times distance$

replace Force for Torque and distance for *angle*

$Work = Torque \times angle$

So you'll need to work out the angle turned through, from the amount of cord unwound.

Comment: that is what I thought of doing but the book just uses the length of the chord as displacement which I assume is to make it easier for someone but it just threw me off so had to ask. Thanks

Comment: you are probably doing it right, does it give the radius, if it's 1 metre the angle in radians and the length of cord would be the same...